# Setting website description on facebook share meta tags?

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to create a webpage that contains the open graph meta tags to make a share into Facebook. My question is: Where should I put the description of the website that appears at the bottom of the description grayed out (the one pointed on the image below)?

Is there a meta tag for this?
[image]

Comment: Pretty sure we always show the domain. Why do you want to hide the domain for the user?

Comment: I don't want to hide the domain.. what i'm trying to do is to change it

Comment: We take the domain from the URL you share. So what is wrong with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where the domain of the document is displayed.

This preview also displays the 'author' of the website:

`<meta name="author" content="John Smith">`

Would result in

> your-domain.com | By John Smith

As far as I am aware, that is all that you can get displayed there.